# How to debug multiple threads in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, push-notification

I'm trying to fix an issue in an unfamiliar piece of code/architecture where i have only a vague sense of what is going on.

I've basically been sticking print statements everywhere i see, going from when the app is backgrounded to `onResume()`. some time between `onResume()` and i actually see a list view updated properly on my device, something is happening to cause a 2 second delay. i can't seem to find it because none of the code in `onResume()` seems to make mods to the listview.

there's a suspicion that the 2 second delay issue is stemming from the fact that i'm re-opening the app from the Notification as opposed to just regularly. problem is, there are multiple threads in notification and i don't really understand what any of it is doing.

What are some ways to go about approaching this problem in terms of "debugging" this? like... does Android Studio have a way to show ALL threads that are in my app at any given point in time? and if so, is this something i can and understand/gather useful information from?

Answer (score 1):

Try [using TraceView](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to narrow down where this delay is coming from. It shows what work is being done and which thread it's running on.